# __fastfail alternative for Linux?

Tags: c++, linux, winapi, sentry, multiplatform

Our codebase uses Sentry to handle crashes, but due to some edge cases, we had to use `__fastfail(FAST_FAIL_FATAL_APP_EXIT)`.

Of course, this is a windows specific function, so I was wondering if there was a Linux alternative to it.
Or rather, if what this function does is already what the default exit() function does for Linux.

The idea of `__fastfail` is to terminate the calling process with minimum overhead.

We made linux release use `exit()`, though due to the limited amount of Linux testers we have, and the edge cases being rare, unsure if it had the desired effect.

Comment: abort(3) looks like what you want

Comment: @SeverinPappadeux `std::abort` causes a signal that may call a signal handler. That's not close to `__fastfail`.

Comment: Maybe [std::_Exit](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/_Exit) is what you are looking for? Or maybe [std::quick_exit](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/quick_exit)?

Comment: `kill(getpid(), SIGKILL)`

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I wonder whether this is guaranteed to be safe, on Linux and on other POSIX systems. In principle `kill` can return and continue executing instructions. Is it guaranteed that the `SIGKILL` signal takes effect immediately at the `kill` syscall without returning to user space, so that the `kill` function can't ever return?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`_exit(2)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/exit.2.html) terminates the calling process "immediately".

By the way [`exit(3)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/exit.3.html) has a reference to `_exit(2)`.

Comment: `std::_Exit` is the standard C++ function for termination without cleanup and has equivalent behavior according to the man page (in the libc implementation that the man page refers to, i.e. glibc).

Comment: "immediately" is probably nothing more than a single syscall (in a loop), for example in musl: https://github.com/bminor/musl/blob/master/src/exit/_Exit.c

Comment: `std::quick_exit` may be what OP is looking for.

Comment: @JesperJuhl `std::quick_exit` is the same as `std::_Exit`, except that it first calls the `std::at_quick_exit`-registered functions. So it is strictly less "immediate".